# Using unix tools(without resorting to R), how to filter the rows based on some statistics of the grouping?

Tags: perl, unix, command-line, awk, filter

I'd like to filter rows of the following table such that it goes from this :

```
A   1   3   SOME_OTHER_INFO
A   1   4   SOME_OTHER_INFO2
A   2   5   SOME_OTHER_INFO3
B   1   1   SOME_OTHER_INFO4
B   2   3   SOME_OTHER_INFO4
B   2   0   SOME_OTHER_INFO4
```

to that:

```
A   1   3   SOME_OTHER_INFO
A   2   5   SOME_OTHER_INFO3
B   1   1   SOME_OTHER_INFO4
B   2   0   SOME_OTHER_INFO4
```

Filtering criteria is this:

1) based on the first 2 columns, group rows.

2) Then for each group, select the row where the third column is minimum within group.

3) Return.

Now it's easy to do something like this in `R` using the package such as `plyr` using commands like this:

```
ddply(data, .(first_col, second_col), function(x) { 
                min_idx = which.min(x$third_col); 
                return(x[min_idx]) 
                })
```

But I want to know if there is a **efficient & elegant way** to do this using unix tools on a command line.

Lastly,  I almost found the beautiful solution to this using `datamash`, which is a recently tool released in GNU, but with some glitches.

```
$ datamash -g 1,2 min 3 -f < file.txt | cut -f1-4

A 1 3 SOME_OTHER_INFO1
A 2 5 SOME_OTHER_INFO3
B 1 1 SOME_OTHER_INFO4
B 2 3 SOME_OTHER_INFO4 # <-- not the correct row I want to grab
```

The problem was when using "-f" flag, it grabs the first item from each group, not the row that min corresponds to. So if you look at the output above "B 2 3 SOME_OTHER_INFO4" was selected rather than "B 2 0 SOME_OTHER_INFO4".

Comment: Sounds like your problem with database is that you didn't sort first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are couple of more options using `perl`:

```
perl -MList::Util=min -lane'
  $h{"@F[0,1]"}{$F[2]} = $_ 
}{
  print $h{$_}{ min keys %{$h{$_}} } for sort keys %h
' file
A   1   3   SOME_OTHER_INFO
A   2   5   SOME_OTHER_INFO3
B   1   1   SOME_OTHER_INFO4
B   2   0   SOME_OTHER_INFO4
```

- Create a hash of hash having inner key as the first two columns and outer key as the third column.
- Using the core module `min` method grab the smallest outer key and print the value which is the entire line.

or without the core module:

```
perl -lane'
    push @{ $h{"@F[0,1]"} }, [$F[2], $_] 
}{ 
    print $_->[1] for sort map { 
        (sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @$_)[0] 
    } values %h
' file
A   1   3   SOME_OTHER_INFO
A   2   5   SOME_OTHER_INFO3
B   1   1   SOME_OTHER_INFO4
B   2   0   SOME_OTHER_INFO4
```

- Create a hash of arrays using key as first two columns and the value as array of third column and the entire line.
- Pull the hash entries by values and sort based on the first element of the array.
- Using slice just grab the first smallest entry and print the second element which is the entire line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask what `}{` construct is in your code? This is unsearchable in google :( !

Comment: @Alby You're welcome. The [`}{`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Eskimo_greeting) is called an eskimo greeting operator. It acts as an `END` block used in `perl` one-liners.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno what you call efficient or elegant, but this seems to be what you want:

```
sort -k1 -k2,3n file.txt | rev | uniq -f 2 | rev
```

If the double rev is considered inelegant (or the actual number of columns varies, in which case it won't work),

```
sort -k1 -k2,3n file.txt | perl -wane'print if $.==1 || $F[0] ne $last[0] || $F[1] != $last[1]; @last=@F'
```

Comment: I'm sorry; you are correct. I guess I mixed it up with another option.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you can get the lines sorted in the right order, a simple Awk filter which prints only the first line in a group should work.

```
sort -k1 -k2n -k3n file.txt |
awk '!a[$1 $2]++'
```

The Awk script populates an array `a` with keys from the first two fields, and prints only when it sees a new key.

Answer (score 0):

How about an elegant, efficient regex?

```
perl -pi'.old' -0777 -e 's/^([a-z]\t[0-9]\t)([0-9]\t\w+\s*)^(\g1[0-9]\t\w+\s*){1,}/$1$2/smgi' file.txt
```

Slurps in `file.txt` and replaces consecutive lines where the first two columns are identical with the first occurrence of the line. This version modifies `file.txt` in place but backs up the original file as `file.txt.old`.